# I've read a lot about the 2d array but I'm having troubles using it on my assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

[Here is the link to the assignment](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j69sfa0mfiqmra1/Lab%204-Arrays.pdf?dl=0)

I managed to get the majority of the project working except the `void finalSales()` function. I'm not too sure how to go about it with a one and two-dimensional array and display it accordingly. I have a midterm exam coming up next week and this chapter is included. I added some comments on what the functions do below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isPlaying = true, isPlaying_Two = true, isPlaying_Three = true, isLooping = true;
string salesPerson[6] = { "Jericho Rosales", "lisa Soberano", "Kim Chiu", "maja Salvador", "Katheryn Bern", "Daniel Padilla" },
items[3] = { "Washing Machine", "Refrigerator", "Music System" };

double table[6][3], totalSales[6] = {0};

int salesNum, productNum;
double saleAmount;


void Sales();
void person();
void prod();
void finalSales();


int main()
{
    while (isLooping) {
       Sales();
    }
    
}

//main game 
void Sales() {

    while (isPlaying)
    {
        person();

        if (salesNum > 0 && salesNum < 7) {
            //cout << "debug " << salesPerson[salesNum - 1];//debug
            cout << "\n";
            while (isPlaying_Two)
            {
                prod();
               
                if (productNum > 0 && productNum < 4) {
                    //cout << "debug " << items[productNum - 1];//debug

                    while (isPlaying_Three)
                    {
                        finalSales();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\n";
                    cout << "Input out of range, please try again\n";
                    cout << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Input out of range, please try again\n";
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}

//user selects which salesperson

    void person() {
        cout << "Sales Registry\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << salesPerson[i] << "\n";
        }

        cout << "Select the Salesperson by typing his ordinal number: ";
        cin >> salesNum;

        //check if cin failed
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
            cin >> salesNum;
        }
    }


    //user selects which product
    void prod() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << items[i] << "\n";
        }

        cout << "Select the product by typing the product ordinal number: ";
        cin >> productNum;

        //check if cin failed
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
            cin >> productNum;
        }
   }

    //get the sales amount(enter a random number in) and 
    //if the user wants to enter more sales it goes back to the beginning and asks again while remembering the previous values
    //if not then the program adds up the amount (if there is more than one) and displays it accordingly to the salesperson and the product
    void finalSales() {
        string again;

        cout << "Enter the sales amount: ";
        cin >> saleAmount;

        //check if cin failed
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
            cin >> saleAmount;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to enter more sales? Type y for yes and n for no: ";
        cin >> again;

        //check if cin failed
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
            cin >> saleAmount;
        }

        if (again == "y" || again == "Y") {
            Sales();
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Salesperson" << "\t\t" << "Washing Machine" << "\t\t" << "Refrigerator" << "\t\t" << "Music system\n";
            cout << "****************************************************************************************************";
            cout << "\n";
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                cout << salesPerson[x];

                for (int y = 0; y < 3 ; y++)
                {
                    
                    cout << "\t\t\t" << table[x][y]; 
                }
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should have made the functions person, prod call themselves if they don't have the right index value since it's in the lab description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return index from `person()` and `prod()` then pass them to `finalSales`. Also pass array to it and increase the amount of product by the `saleAmount`. And don't forget to make your bool variables `false` or you end up with infinite loop. Create two int variables in `Sales()`. Initialize them by returning the index from `person()` and the other one from `product()`.

```
void finalSales(int idx1, int idx2,double table[6][3]) {
    string again;
    
    cout << "Enter the sales amount: ";
    cin >> saleAmount;
    table[idx1][ idx2] = saleAmount;
    //check if cin failed
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
        cin >> saleAmount;
    }

    cout << "Do you want to enter more sales? Type y for yes and n for no: ";
    cin >> again;

    //check if cin failed
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
        cin >> saleAmount;
    }

    if (again == "y" || again == "Y") {
        Sales();
    }
    else {
        ::isPlaying_Three = false;
        ::isPlaying_Two = false;
        ::isPlaying = false;
        ::isLooping = false;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Salesperson" << "\t\t" << "Washing Machine" << "\t\t" << "Refrigerator" << "\t\t" << "Music system\n";
        cout << "****************************************************************************************************";
        cout << "\n";
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
            cout << salesPerson[x];

            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {

                cout << "\t\t\t" << table[x][y];
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

That's for `person()` and the same for `prod()`.

```
int person() {
    cout << "Sales Registry\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << salesPerson[i] << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Select the Salesperson by typing his ordinal number: ";
    cin >> salesNum;

    //check if cin failed
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << "Invalid entry, enter again ";
        cin >> salesNum;
    }
    return salesNum-1;
}
```

Don't forget to decrease index by 1.